# Flutter runs on non supported iOS version

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I have just generated a new podfile and installed a simulator with iOS 10 on it. The podfile has the ios platform version set to be 11.0, but when i run on the ios 10 simualtor, it installs and opens (although crashes). Why is there not a build/install error as the simulator version is below the podfile platform version.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Have I done something wrong, this is driving me crazy.

--Edit

Updating the following dropdown in the ios folder in xcode
[image]

produces the following differences

```
+++ b/example/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist
@@ -21,6 +21,6 @@
   <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
   <string>1.0</string>
   <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
-  <string>8.0</string>
+  <string>11.0</string>
 </dict>
 </plist>


+++ b/example/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
        archiveVersion = 1;
        classes = {
        };
-       objectVersion = 50;
+       objectVersion = 51;
        objects = {
 
 /* Begin PBXBuildFile section */
@@ -370,6 +370,7 @@
                                        "$(PROJECT_DIR)/Flutter",
                                );
                                INFOPLIST_FILE = Runner/Info.plist;
+                               IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0;
                                LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                                        "$(inherited)",
                                        "@executable_path/Frameworks",
@@ -507,6 +508,7 @@
                                        "$(PROJECT_DIR)/Flutter",
                                );
                                INFOPLIST_FILE = Runner/Info.plist;
+                               IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0;
                                LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                                        "$(inherited)",
                                        "@executable_path/Frameworks",
@@ -538,6 +540,7 @@
                                        "$(PROJECT_DIR)/Flutter",
                                );
                                INFOPLIST_FILE = Runner/Info.plist;
+                               IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0;
                                LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                                        "$(inherited)",
                                        "@executable_path/Frameworks",
```

But it is still happy to install on the ios 10 simulator

Comment: What supported version have you set for your project target, not the version in the pod file

Comment: Where is that located? I have tried opening the ios folder in xcode and updating the dropdown in the general tab to 11.0.... ill update the question to show what my git diff changed although I did this like an hour ago and it didnt seem to make any difference

Comment: That is now showing a minimum deployment target of iOS 11, however if you are using a command line to execute your app on the simulator and not the Xcode GUI there is a good chance that the normal checks are bypassed and it lets you do what you want, even if that doesn't make senses. Rest assured that an app with the Xcode target set to iOS 11 cannot be installed on a real iOS device running iOS 10

Comment: I have been using android studio, I will try launching with xcode.... but from what I have posted I haven't missed anything?